# Why is ng-repeat not loading variables?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is the code from my JS file and my HTML file. I am getting empty table rows, but I am getting 4 of them, so everything is properly hooked up. Any idea what's going on here? Using angular 1.3.15

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
$scope.vals = [
        {
      "name": "Orders",
      "value": 12
    },
    {
      "name": "Customers",
      "value": 100
    },
    {
      "name": "Dollars",
      "value": 1000
    },
    {
      "name": "Dollars",
      "value": 1000
    }
    ];
});
```

```
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="v in vals">
            <td>{{ v.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ v.value }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

EDIT: The outputted HTML is:

```
<table>
        <tbody><!-- ngRepeat: v in vals --><tr ng-repeat="v in vals" class="ng-scope">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: v in vals --><tr ng-repeat="v in vals" class="ng-scope">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: v in vals --><tr ng-repeat="v in vals" class="ng-scope">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: v in vals --><tr ng-repeat="v in vals" class="ng-scope">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: v in vals -->
    </tbody></table>
```

Comment: Something else is wrong, here is a direct copy and paste of your code into a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/nubixakige/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: @mergesort: Your code works with me. Check if you link with angularjs library, load angularjs code in right place (head or body tag).

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: not getting any error. added the resulting HTML

Comment: @mergesort, can you post a broken [jsBin](http://jsbin.com)?  None of us can recreate your issue with what you've supplied us -- it all works.

Comment: I am loading this in an iFrame for a shopify app. I am also using flask, so posting a broken jsBin is difficult. When I paste the code in jsBin it works, but when I put it into my app it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using flask, which uses Jinja for templating. In my template I had {{ v.name }}, which jinja interpolates. I added an angular filter, which allows angular to do what it needs to without jinja interfering. I had this issue before and just forgot.

Nice waste of a couple of hours!

Answer (score -1):

It does work for me, without changing anything of your code. 
(May be it is a `CSS` issue?).
Since you say that you see 4 rows, then it is probably not an Angular issue.

here is a jsFidle : https://jsfiddle.net/shimonb/h44rduky/